# How do I extract files inside a bundle?

Tags: android

Would you like to know how to extract a file extension "* .bundle"?
This bundle file contains several files inside as if it were a ZIP, among these files, has a text file of application strings and I need to open to translate it from Chinese to English.
I know there is a way to manipulate because there are people translating this same application, just for other languages.

--- EDIT ---

File: [File.bundle](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/605529213176643588/647639807601934346/46939c6538613036d27f3d578d58ecf6.bundle)

Comment: `Would you like to know` are you sure it is your question? Probably that's you whoul would like to know something?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a reverse engineering to APK, 
Download dex2jar tool from [dex2jar](https://github.com/pxb1988/dex2jar).

Once the JAR file is generated, use [JD-GUI](http://jd.benow.ca/) to open the JAR file. You will see the Java files

Comment: The file ".bundle" is outside the ".apk", it is update file. So I think this reverse engineering method in apk doesn't solve my problem. But thanks for the reply.